# Need to be able to change Font size across an entire application for accesibility

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-experience, uiaccessibility

I have built a GIS routing application, using WPF, MVVM, and Visual Studio 2015.

When I test the app on a laptop, the fonts seem smaller than when I tested in debug mode on my pc.

Is there a way to create a feature in my application settings so a user could increase the size of all of the fonts, globally, without affecting the graphics? I was hoping this would be similar to a webpage design with the 'ctrl +'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've added similar functionality to my application using ViewBox. Note, it doesn't change the font size, but instead "zooms" all aspects of the user interface. Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but this is what it looks like to give you an idea:

[image]

To get this, I wrapped the highest level View (that hosts all content, this could be done on the Window level) in a ViewBox, and then bound the Width and Height to properties in the ViewModel that I could edit using a "zoom" amount:

```
<Viewbox SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
    <DockPanel Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
          ...content...
    </DockPanel>
</ViewBox>
```

With the width and height:

```
    private int BaseWidth = 1150;
    private int BaseHeight = 750;

    public int Width
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)(BaseWidth * appSettings.Zoom);
        }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)(BaseHeight * appSettings.Zoom);
        }
    }
```

This not only allows the application to be resolution independent (everything wont look tiny on a large DPI screen) it will also allow users to scale if they are having trouble reading things, or if they simply prefer it.

Pretty simple. To effect only font size, you should probably be looking at building style templates for the components. I'd bet you'd catch a lot of the text by simply setting a global TextBlock style with the font size - not sure how dynamic you can be with the default styles.

**Edit: Try this with styles:**

```
<sys:Double x:Key="BaseFontSize">12</sys:Double>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource BaseFontSize}"/>
</Style>
```

You might have to have a list of wpf controls (buttons, checkboxes, textboxes etc etc) but it wouldn't be too difficult.

BaseFontSize should be able to be changed. All controls without a style set will use this as default if it's in window or app resources. So you won't need to go through all the controls making sure they have a style set.

Comment: I have a settings view that controls things globally. Is this something that I could put on there and affect the rest of the views in the application, rather than having to adjust each view?

Comment: Does your settings view "host" (have the other views as a direct child?), or is it simply a view that contains the UI for settings?

Comment: If you have no view that sits on top of everything and contains every sub-view in, say, a ContentControl, then I suggest you add the ViewBox directly to the Window, or create a simple Navagation/Host View and ViewModel. It depends how your GUI is structured, a quick diagram/screenshot might be helpful. Are you using a MVVM framework? How are your Views structured?

Comment: the settings view is a child of the main window view... but not a direct child. creatively I would say direct grandchild, maybe... if that makes sense. But I see where you are going with this... I have to talk with the business side of things to effect the main window... which I am going to do now...

Comment: Yeah, the higher up you go in the WPF layout tree, the more stuff you effect. Anything inside the viewbox gets "zoomed", so if you don't want to put a ViewBox in every View you need to have it in the UserControl that hosts those views.

At a window level, everything in the whole application will scale, which is probably what you want.

Comment: So after a short conference, they only want the font size to change, mainly due to the GIS functions of the application. I was thinking of trying the same method except instead of height and width, make fontsize the dynamic feature... but this seems that it would create problems with the controls.

Comment: I've done this with a ScaleTransform but this is simpler. Very slick.

Comment: I'm afraid it wouldn't work the same way with font size. You'll have to take a look at styles I think

Comment: My app has styles already, but other developer that worked on it didn't always use styles so it would be very time consuming to reconfigure every text to have a dynamic font size.

Comment: You can change those styles where applicable, but also override the default style used when no style is explicitly applied by just not setting a key. I'll add to my answer.

Comment: then I would be able to dynamically set the value of "BaseFontSize" to the users preference... Awesome!